# Rewrite part of request url as variable on php script with nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
domain.com/account/manage/somekey/  ->  domain.com/account/manage/?key=somekey
domain.com/account/manage/somekey/settings/  ->  domain.com/account/manage/settings/?key=somekey
```

somekey being a string containg A-F,a-f,0-9 24 characters in length.

This is what I have for the first one, but I'm not sure how to do the second.

```
location /account/manage/  {
     rewrite "^/account/manage/([A-Fa-f0-9]{24})/(.*)$" /account/manage/?key=$1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /account/manage/ {
    rewrite "^/account/manage/([A-Fa-f0-9]{24})/(settings/)?" /account/manage/$2?key=$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with nginx, but try this version:

```
location /account/manage/$  {
  rewrite ^/account/manage/([A-Fa-f0-9]+)(/[^/]*)?/?$ /account/manage$2/?key=$1;
  try_files $uri $uri/;
}
```